# Chrome shows frame-src error even if using object

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, content-security-policy

i have the following Html

```
<object data="https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfile.pdf" class="t-document-view" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

and the following CSP

```
"default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self'; object-src https://*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com; connect-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; report-uri /csp/report;"
```

On all the machine with chrome browser we can view PDF without issue. However, one of our machine we are getting error

> Refused to frame 'https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "child-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'child-src' is used as a fallback.

To get rid of the error i have temporarily added `frame-src https://*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com;` and its working

I have already set `object-src` so not sure why its trying to implement `frame-src` policy when we are not using frame?

Google Chrome is up to date
Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I'm getting this too after upgrading from "Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)" to "Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)". Looks like Chrome introduced a CSP bug

Comment: I filed a Chromium bug (don't know if it's publicly visible or not) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1002610